# Ruby inline begin and rescue not performing properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, exception

I have the following code

```
'Performance' => {
    'Date' => performance_values.date.strftime('%m/%d/%Y'),
    'Ratio' => begin sprintf("%0.02f", performance_values.ratio) rescue nil end},
'Ratings' => {
    'Overall' => performance_values.overall_rating,
    '3-yr' => performance_values.3yr_rating}
```

With 'Ratio' it can sometimes be nil, so I'm trying to begin/rescue out of the `sprintf` function and just let it be nil.

When this runs and `performance_values.ratio` is nil, i get the following error message:

```
TypeError: can't convert nil into Float
```

Comment: Under what version? If I run something that's more or less this under `irb` it works fine, other than I'm substituting `nil` for `performance_values.ratio`.

Comment: Jruby 1.7.11 Ruby 1.9.  It seems to work fine under IRB but it doesn't seem to work in my project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Being inline, you don't need to specify `begin` & `end`. Rails knows  that you are rescuing the whole line.

Try this:

```
'Performance' => {
    'Date' => performance_values.date.strftime('%m/%d/%Y'),
    'Ratio' => (sprintf("%0.02f", performance_values.ratio) rescue nil)},
'Ratings' => {
    'Overall' => performance_values.overall_rating,
    '3-yr' => performance_values.3yr_rating}
```